# String concatenation error

Tags: javascript, concatenation

I have a HTMl form

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>
        Banner Ad Name :<br />
        <input type="text" name="bannerAdName" id="bannerAdName" />
    </p>
    <p>
        Your web page :<br />
        <input type="text" name="bannerAdWeb" id="bannerAdWeb" />
    </p>
    <p>
        Ad image :<br />
        <input type="file" name="bannerAdImage" id="bannerAdImage"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        Title :<br />
        <input type="text" name="bannerAdTitle" id="bannerAdTitle" />
    </p>
    <p>
        Description :<br />
        <textarea name="bannerAdDesc" id="bannerAdDesc" ></textarea>
    </p>
    <div id="button"><input type="button" value="VIEW" onclick="return upload()"/></div>

    <input type="hidden" value="POST" />
</form>
```

And a Javascript

```
<div id="banAdT">

                                   <script>
                        document.getElementById("bannerAdWeb").onchange = function() {
                        document.getElementById("banAdT").innerHTML = '<a href="'+this.value+'">';
                        }
                    </script>

                    <script>
                        document.getElementById("bannerAdTitle").onchange = function() {
                        var u = this.value;
                        document.getElementById("banAdT").innerHTML += u;
                        document.getElementById("banAdT").innerHTML += '</a>';
                        alert(document.getElementById("banAdT").innerHTML);
                        }
                    </script> 
    </div>
```

I am expecting the alert to show something like `<a href="someurl">Some Title</a>` . But instead it shows `<a href="someurl"></a>Some Title` ! Please help..I can't find where I have done the wrong

Comment: Where is the element with an ID `banAdT`?

Comment: @Nitish could you please edit your question? It doesn't make any sense: "I am expecting the alert to show something like Some Title. But instead it shows Some Title"

Comment: @Nitish I realized the problem was you didn't formatted your question correctly. You must use proper formatting for code blocks so that HTML code is visible. It's been fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
            <script>
                document.getElementById("bannerAdWeb").onchange = function() {
                document.getElementById("banAdT").innerHTML = '<a id="bandAdTLink" href="'+this.value+'"></a>';
                }
            </script>

            <script>
                document.getElementById("bannerAdTitle").onchange = function() {
                var u = this.value;
                document.getElementById("bandAdTLink").innerHTML += u;
                alert(document.getElementById("banAdT").innerHTML);
                }
            </script>
```

**Solution explanation**: you should never insert invalid HTML into the DOM via javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put invalid bits of HTML into the DOM and expect them to remain. The browser will error correct, e.g.

```
document.getElementById("banAdT").innerHTML = '<a href="'+this.value+'">';
```

That will be error corrected by the browser to an empty A element.

```
var u = this.value;
document.getElementById("banAdT").innerHTML += u;
```

That will likely append a u character after the A element.

```
document.getElementById("banAdT").innerHTML += '</a>';
```

No idea what the browser will make of that, it is literally creating:

```
<a href="..."></a>u</a>
```

so whatever happens is browser dependent.

Use DOM methods, don't mess around with innerHTML and string manipulation for non-trivial stuff. E.g. create the A element like:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = this.value;
```

and later

```
a.appendChild(document.createTextNode('u'));
```

then append the a element something like:

```
document.getElementById("banAdT").apppendChild(a);
```

Answer (score -1):

The problematic code is this:

```
document.getElementById("banAdT").innerHTML += u;
document.getElementById("banAdT").innerHTML += '</a>';
```

Those should be `document.getElementById("bannerAdTitle").value`.

Comment: Input elements don't have innerHTML.

Comment: @shinkou This was from the original code posted by Nitish. I was pointing out that the element ID he was using was wrong. Of course you're right that there's a second problem with his code. I've updated my answer to reflect your comment, thanks